# SQL server login error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, login

I am trying to login to SQL server 2005, and it gives me an error 18456..

This is very funny...I go to advanced option and set network protocol as TCP/IP it does not work..if I leave it as default it works....

I remember we user TCP/IP authentication....why is this an issue ?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe TCP/IP is not enabled on your server? Check out [this website](http://blogs.msdn.com/sql_protocols/archive/2006/02/21/536201.aspx) for more information.